# UI Automation AlertPrompt button/textField accessiblity

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uialertview, ios-ui-automation

I'm having a bit of trouble with UI Automation (the built in to iOS tool) when it comes to alertView. First off, I'm not sure where I can set the accessibilityLabel and such for the buttons that are on the alertView. Secondly, although I am not getting an error, I can't get my textField to actually set the value of the textField to something. I'll put up my code for the alertView and the javaScript I am using for UI Automation.

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert)
{
    // Log alerts and bail, unless it's the one we want
    var title = alert.name();
    UIALogger.logMessage("Alert with title '" + title + "' encountered!");
    alert.logElementTree();
    if (title == "AlertPrompt")
    {
        UIALogger.logMessage(alert.textFields().length + '');
        target.delay(1);
        alert.textFields()["AlertText"].setValue("AutoTest");
        target.delay(1);

        return true; // Override default handler
    }
    else
        return false;
}


var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var application = target.frontMostApp(); 
var mainWindow = application.mainWindow();
mainWindow.logElementTree();

//target.delay(1);
//mainWindow.logElementTree();
//target.delay(1);

var tableView = mainWindow.tableViews()[0];
var button = tableView.buttons();
//UIALogger.logMessage("Num buttons: " + button.length);
//UIALogger.logMessage("num Table views: " + mainWindow.tableViews().length);

//UIALogger.logMessage("Number of cells: " + tableView.cells().length);

/*for (var currentCellIndex = 0; currentCellIndex < tableView.cells().length; currentCellIndex++)
{
    var currentCell = tableView.cells()[currentCellIndex];
    UIALogger.logStart("Testing table option: " + currentCell.name());
    tableView.scrollToElementWithName(currentCell.name());
    target.delay(1);
    currentCell.tap();// Go down a level
    target.delay(1);

    UIATarget.localTarget().captureScreenWithName(currentCell.name());
    //mainWindow.navigationBar().leftButton().tap(); // Go back
    target.delay(1);
    UIALogger.logPass("Testing table option " + currentCell.name());
}*/

UIALogger.logStart("Testing add item");
target.delay(1);
mainWindow.navigationBar().buttons()["addButton"].tap();
target.delay(1);
if(tableView.cells().length == 5)
    UIALogger.logPass("Successfully added item to table");
else
    UIALogger.logFail("FAIL: didn't add item to table");
```

Here's what I'm using for the alertView

```
#import "AlertPrompt.h"

@implementation AlertPrompt
@synthesize textField;
@synthesize enteredText;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle okButtonTitle:(NSString *)okayButtonTitle withOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation
{

    if ((self == [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:okayButtonTitle, nil]))
    {
        self.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
        self.accessibilityLabel = @"AlertPrompt";
        UITextField *theTextField;
        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
            theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
        else
            theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 30.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
        [theTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
        [self addSubview:theTextField];
        self.textField = theTextField;

        self.textField.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
        self.textField.accessibilityLabel = @"AlertText";
        [theTextField release];
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0); 
        [self setTransform:translate];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)show
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [super show];
}
- (NSString *)enteredText
{
    return [self.textField text];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    //[textField release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign accessibility name to your view most probably you should try to implement accessibility methods for whole view (i'm not sure what you are subclassing for AlertPrompt class in header).

Try to add these methods for the AlertPrompt implementation:

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)accessibilityLabel {  // will translate to accessibility .name() in UI javascript
    return [NSString stringWithString:@"AlertPrompt"];
}

- (NSString *)accessibilityValue { // will translate to accessibility .value() in UI javascript
    return [NSString stringWithString:@"AlertString"];
}
```

Then log element tree and make sure you can access your view/alert accessibility properties via .name() and .value() methods in UI javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try this and get back to you with results when I can test this!

Comment: Ok this did work for the name (the previous implementation worked as well but this seems much more clean). However, I can't seem to get the .defaultButton() to work (I thought that defaultButton() was a callable item for alerts), and my textField doesn't seem to be showing up in the logElementTree. Any ideas as to what else could be wrong? Thanks by the way for the cleaner implementation of the accessibility labels and such!

Comment: One idea why you don't see textField in your element tree is because you are setting accessibility label to self.textField but not for the theTextField which you actually are adding to your View. Try to set accessibility for theTextField before adding it to view.